# Loading image from URL in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, image-loading

I use below code to load image from URL in my winodws phone 7 application.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/80000/5000/100/85108/85108.strip.print.gif", UriKind.Absolute)
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

It is working fine for me. But image is loading asynchronously and by the time I want to show some kind of busy indicator there and if image does not exist on such URL then I want to show some default image. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are subscribed to the [Image.ImageFailed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you should be able to show to default image in case of a non-existing image.

Conditions in which this event can occur include the following:

1. File not found.
2. Invalid (unrecognized or unsupported) file format.
3. Unknown file format decoding error after upload.

So something like this might work for you:

```
image1.ImageFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(handlerImageFailed);
Uri uri = new Uri("http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/80000/5000/100/85108/85108.strip.print.gif", UriKind.Absolute)
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);

void handlerImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Show the default image
}
```

Comment: If image exists then I want to show some progressbar or busy indicator while it loads from URL. Can you please provide the sample code for it?

Comment: This concept is ok but what if image exists there but it takes time to load. I want to show indicator there in the meanwhile time.

Comment: I think you should show busy indicator in both cases (if image exists or not). I dont have a code example right now but explore the [BusyIndicator control here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg315125).

Comment: Also, please read this: [Silverlight does not support GIF files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).